# How to fix Error 400 Image not displaying Next App firebase ssr

Tags: reactjs, next.js, firebase-hosting

Still in my journey of deploying my ssr app on firebase. Almost there.

I only have an issue with my images. I am getting a 400 error message on the console. Pictures are from an external url. The data fetched is correct but it does display somehow. You will see below my `server.js` file and next.config.js.

Can someone tell me what is missing, please?

server.js

```
const { https } = require('firebase-functions');
const { default: next } = require('next');

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const server = next({
    dev: isDev,
    //location of .next generated after running -> yarn build
    conf: { distDir: '.next' },
    image :{ domain :['assets.coingecko.com'],}
});

const nextjsHandle = server.getRequestHandler();
exports.nextServer = https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return server.prepare()
        .then(() => {
            return nextjsHandle(req, res)
        });
});
```

next.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
//const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
//const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');



module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['assets.coingecko.com'],
    loader: 'imgix',
    path: 'https://assets.coingecko.com/',
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  entry: './src/index.js',
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      //...
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  //...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Fetching an image from Firebase storage using next/image results in a 400 status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65601999/fetching-an-image-from-firebase-storage-using-next-image-results-in-a-400-status)? The next/image configuration needs to be added inside the `conf` object in `server.js`.

Comment: Hi @juliomalves thanks for your contribution. i have seen this one but i am not sure how i can apply this to my code. how do i add my config to distDir?

Comment: You don't add it to `distDir`, you add it to the `conf` object, i.e. `conf: { distDir: '.next', images: { domains: ['assets.coingecko.com'] } }`.

Comment: @juliomalves when i try it i say join not defined.  i have added it like this const nextjsDistDir = join("src", require("./next.config.js").distDir);


const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const server = next({
    dev: isDev,
    //location of .next generated after running -> yarn build
    conf: { distDir: nextjsDistDir },
    image :{ domain :['assets.coingecko.com'],}
});

Comment: Where does `join` come from? Did you try the approach of the top answer on the question I linked?

Comment: @juliomalves thanks. i did tried the one below.  i have did as per  the first question, i am receiving error 500 could not handle request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239228/discussion-between-leo-and-juliomalves).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I wanted to thank you for your help @juliomalves.

I found the answer to my issue. [I have answered the questions in detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69974890/how-to-set-up-next-image-loader-url-correctly-for-external-url/70052871#70052871)
if anyone finds himself in the same situation.